# Windows form controls become grey overlay

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview

I have created a winform application in vb.net, it contains a parent container and other child forms. When one of the child form which contains a data gridview with some cell formatting, loading the other controls became gray colour overlayed.

[image: Screenshot]

**Note**: the gridview is created using the data from database and the color is applied according to the value in the cells. The color changing using the cellformating method. I have tried double buffering.. but it didn't help. In red color circle it is label and in green color, it is button.

Find the code below for cell formatting:

```
  Private Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.CellFormatting
    Try
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To dataGridView1.RowCount
            If (i = (dataGridView1.RowCount)) Then
                Exit For
            Else
                Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString())
                dt = dt.AddHours(12)
                Dim ts As TimeSpan = dt.Subtract(DateTime.Now)
                Dim s As String = dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString()
                If s = "Ready to Collect" Then
                    dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen
                    dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = "-----"
                ElseIf s = "Completed" Then
                    dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
                    dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = "-----"
                ElseIf s = "Out of Stock" Then
                    dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                    dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = "-----"
                ElseIf s = "Sent" Then
                    dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
                    If ts.CompareTo(TimeSpan.Zero) < 0 Then
                        dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = "Process Immediately"
                        dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Style.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
                    Else
                        dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes)
                    End If
                ElseIf s = "Cancelled" Then
                    dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Style.BackColor = Color.White
                    dataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = "-----"
                End If
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Show code, how you setting color to datagridview and other controls

Comment: I think the parent form backColor is gray and child controls have transparently ! when a control backcolor is transparent then that control get parent color to self! test that controls backcolor is not transparent

Comment: no it is control light....

Comment: For me it's look like `BackColor` and `ForeColor` of controls are both same color.

Comment: no.. its not... when i drag the form to another position, it become normal...

Comment: But there could be code somewhere that sets the forecolor accidentally

Comment: as i have already said, its going back to normal when i am trying to move the window by click and drag... and there is no issue when i remove all code from cell_formatting method... Hope you got me..

Comment: Remove `Try Catch` from the code in the `CellFormatting` eventhandler. May be exception was thrown, which affect on the colors drawing

Comment: itz not working... thanx anyway...

Comment: Form repainted, when you move form around. Because colors became normal after you move form, I think your code affect some Error exception which prevent to properly draw the form in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Check [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Maybe this helps you.

Comment: DoEvents is evil.  It introduces more problems than it solves.  It was used extensively in VB6, but it has no place in VB.Net programming.  It is simply not needed.  Rather than using DoEvents, the original poster should put any long running code in a background worker so the UI can continue to be responsive.